# Why is looping over a container and modifying it considered bad practice?

Tags: c++

I would like to understand why it is considered bad practice to do this. I do get the "desired" output when printing the vector. (1,2,4,5).

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (auto it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it)
    {
        // Accessing invalidated iterator leads to undefined behavior
        if (*it == 3)
        {
            numbers.erase(it); // Invalidates the iterator
        }
    }

    for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),([](int x){cout << x << '\n';}));
}
```

I know I could also do:

```
numbers.erase(std::remove(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 3), numbers.end());
```

By I want to understand why the first approach can lead to undefined behavior and what is happening underneath.

Comment: Depends on the modification.   If using iterators to control the loop, a number of operations (e.g. adding or removing elements) invalidates the iterators being used to control the loop, so using them to control the loop causes undefined behaviour (which can cause subtle problems that are hard to pick up in testing, but cause errors for end users). While it is possible to correct that (e.g. obtain valid iterators before continuing) it is easy to implement that incorrectly (making problems worse).   In practice, it is often easier (more concise, less error prone) to use alternative approaches.

Comment: Always check your container documentation, for some containers it is not a problem. For others it is completely not allowed since iterators will get invalidated. Als just learn to use functions like [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). Using those functions will be correct and more readable

Comment: Change `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` to `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3}` and watch the bad practice happen in action.

Answer (score 8):

`numbers.erase(it)` will invalidate the iterator `it`, it can no longer be used for anything. It no longer "point" to an element that exists in the vector. The iterator has been "disconnected" from the vector.

You should instead use the iterator that the `erase` function [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase#Return_value) as the "next" iterator (and skip `++it`).

---

For a simple example of what *can* happen, think about the case where you remove the last element from the vector. You then increase the iterator to point to.... Where? Increasing the iterator will not make it point to the `end` iterator, and since it's "disconnected" from the vector it used to belong to, there's really no way to ell exactly what or where it might "point" to.

So to continue with the example of erasing the last element, you will do an invalid increase, and invalid comparison which will likely be true (since the invalid iterator will not be the same as the vector `end` iterator) and the loop will continue forever.

But even just erasing an element in the middle will invalidate the iterator, so no matter for which element you call erase, using the same iterator again leads to *undefined behavior* (which is an *error*, and not only a bad practice).

---

For completeness, here's the loop as it should be:

```
for (auto it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); /* Empty */)
{
    if (*it == 3)
    {
        // Erase the element, and get an iterator to the element after the erased
        // Or if it's the last element then get the end iterator
        it = numbers.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
        // Not erasing element, increase iterator to point to the next element
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of what makes Undefined Behavior so insidious and difficult to deal with -- your code may *appear* to work fine when in fact it is broken and when you change something apparently unrelated, all hell will break loose, making it very hard to figure out where the actual problem is.

Because std::vector iterators are (usually) implemented as pointers into the vector, an operation like `erase` that invalidates the iterator will still leave the iterator as an apparently valid pointer, it just points at the wrong place.  So if you use it, it is easy for it to appear to work, though subtle (or not so subtle) problems may appear later on.  For your specific case, look at what happens if your input vector is something like:

```
std::vector<int> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5};
```

in this case, after erasing the first 3, the iterator will point at the second 3, and then the loop increment will go on to the 4, so the second 3 won't be erased.

Answer (score 2):

"Why is looping over a container and modifying it considered bad practice?" - Because modifying the container potentially invalidates iterators and (potentially) indices. So the iteration suddenly doesn't iterate over what it thought it was iterating over and chaos ensues.